# What is the "path to ant" that Crosswalk speak of?

Tags: java, paths

I am in the process of setting up an Ubuntu 14.04 server to experiment with [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/linux_host_setup.html). I have installed the Java JDK, `apt-get install default-jdk` and ANT, `apt-get install ant`. `whereis java` returns `/usr/bin/java` and `whereis ant` returns `/usr/bin/ant`.  What I find confusing is the next step:Configure The Tools which states

```
export PATH=<path to ant>/bin:<path to JDK>/bin:$PATH
```

It is not clear how I should interpret this.  Left to my own devices I might have done

```
export PATH=/usr/bin/ant
```

but it doesn't look like that is what they are suggesting. This is unknown territory for me.  I would much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the evironment variable `$PATH` specifies the directories in which to look when executing a command. From the [official manual:](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

> When you type a command to run, the system looks for it in the directories specified by PATH in the order specified

You can add directories to `$PATH` with `export PATH="/path/to/executable":$PATH`. Note that the `:` serves as separator between directories and you should only specify the path to the directory which contains the executable file and not the file itself.

In your case you can skip this step, as `java` and `ant` are already found.